# Why is the Python package called Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, if not, please let me know and I will delete the question and ask it there. It didn't look like meta or superuser were the right places for it.

The reason for it is that nothing about the Pandas library makes me think of a Panda.

Comment: it's right here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for **practical**, answerable questions about software development. If the answer to a question doesn't solve a specific technical problem you actually face in the course of practicing software development, that question is off-topic here.

Comment: it predates Desiigner's hit rap single Panda

Comment: @qwr can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: @Julien, to "predate" something is to come before it in time. Thus, the comment is proving that the rap single _doesn't_ answer your question (while maybe poking fun at the question itself). It certainly, then, shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software))

> The name is derived from the term ["**pan**el **da**ta"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data), an [econometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Econometrics) term for [data sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set) that include observations over multiple time periods for the same individuals.

Comment: That is so counterintuitive. Who's heard of "panel data" before?

Comment: I'm not a statistician, but given that the term is well-known enough to have its own Wikipedia page, I'd say it's at least moderately well-known in that field. And the target audience of Pandas is primarily statisticians and data scientists.

Comment: It's an econometrics term. I've never heard of it in traditional statistics or machine learning

Answer (score 2):

From its wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software)#:%7E:text=Its%20name%20is%20a%20play,there%20from%202007%20to%202010.)

> The name is derived from the term "**pan**el **da**ta", an econometrics term for data sets that include observations over multiple time periods for the same individuals.Its name is a play on the phrase "Python data analysi**s**" itself. Wes McKinney started building what would become pandas at AQR Capital while he was a researcher there from 2007 to 2010.